# Writing new classes with fontspec and polyglossia?

Tags: xetex, luatex, best-practices, documentclass-writing

Let me get straight to it: when writing a new document class, should I load `fontspec` and other packages which require LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX?

## Some context

When I was taught to use LaTeX, some 10-odd years ago, I was told to write diacritics using escape codes such as `\^{a}`-like commands. Very quickly I found out that was obsolete and that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` took care of the job.

Most LaTeX introductions don't tell you about LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX or if they do, they treat it as a non-standard solution. In my opinion, that shouldn't be the case. In Portuguese, my mother tongue, we have few but constantly used characters which are not part of ASCII. So, when teaching newcomers to LaTeX, I always tell them to use Lua- or XeLaTeX.

I have never, however, taught how to write LaTeX document classes. I want to teach my students the best practices, so I'd like to know what the community thinks about this topic.

Comment: the future will probably be some combination of lua/xe tex but currently for example most journals accepting tex sources will only accept classic tex, so it depends what use your students need to make of latex. Unless your class actually requires luatex or xetex there is no need to make it fail with pdftex.

Comment: inputenc should cover all Portuguese needs I would think? If you were using cjk or indic scripts with complicated text requirements then the arguments for not supporting 8-bit tex are much stronger.

Comment: While `inputenc` is enough for Portuguese, `fontspec` is a great way of changing fonts. Much less complicated than the old ways. I want my students to be able to create classes for with custom fonts very easily.

Comment: yes sure there are advantages, but also disadvantages, and for most document classes you do not need to make that choice, but it's really impossible to say at this level of generality.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I'll think it through and weigh the pros and cons. I will probably show both pdflatex and lualatex and explain their differences, strengths and shortcomings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- please combine your comments into an answer and get this off the unanswered list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done!

Comment: @rberaldo So you take the credit?

Comment: In my opinion, LaTeX beginners should not write new classes. Classes are for reuse by others and a beginner does not (yet) have the knowledge to provide quality work.

Comment: If possible I write classes for both engine types. E.g. with `\sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF{code for pdflatex}{code for luatex/xelatex}`

Comment: @cfr I misread Barbara's message and thought it was directed to me. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: that's a good idea.

Comment: @Johannes_B Classes don't have to be for use by others. I've never shared a class, despite having several, including one with 40+ pages of documentation.

Comment: I teach students to use pdfTeX unless they need a non-Latin script such as Arabic. I just think an update is less likely to cause a nasty surprise the day before their dissertation deadline ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Classes and packages should usually be engine/font/encoding agnostic

I think there's something being missed here.  By and large neither classes nor packages should make any assumptions with either font or input encodings or engine unless absolutely needed; this should almost always be left to the document level. A class is usually used to set up some particular document *type*: the layout of the pages, section headings, etc.  A package adds a particular functionality to documents of any class, usually.  Of course one can find exceptions to this general rule (see below for some examples). Neither needs to assume properties of the fonts or engines.

Classes and packages should similarly not assume a particular language is being used, and should therefore leave loading `babel` or `polyglossia` to the user as well.

It's one thing to teach students to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as their main engine for their day to day documents (which indeed does make font handling easier) but an entirely different thing to teach them that classes or packages they write should include engine dependent code. This is teaching them bad practices.

### When might a class or package require engine specificity

There are obviously certain times at which it makes sense for a class or package to assume an engine or font setup.

- packages that require Lua code and will only run with LuaTeX
- packages that require XeTeX specific functionality (e.g., `XeTeXinterchartoks`)
- classes that reproduce a particular form with a specified font

These are very specialized uses, and unlikely to be the thing that beginners are ever likely to do.

Comment: I don't think it was really missed. I took it to be David's point ;).

Comment: @cfr I was referring to the now deleted summary and to the question itself.